# Problema al intentar crear un archivo zip con php con rutas obtenidas de una consulta en una base de datos phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, array, foreach, zip

estoy intentando traer archivos almacenados en una base de datos mysql(estoy utilizando phpmyadmin para manejar la base de datos) con php. Mi objetivo es crear un boton de descarga que al presionarlo, cree un archivo zip para poder asi descargarlo.

El boton ya esta creado y funciona correctamente, el problema es que cuando se crea el archivo zip y lo descargo, no lo puedo abrir ya que aparece el mensaje de que "el archivo tiene un formato desconocido o esta dañado".Estoy utilizando la libreria ZipArchive y Windows.

El codigo que estoy utilizando es el siguiente.

```
$registrosPersonalizados = [];
$archivosPersonalizados = $controlador->getArchivostablapersonalizado($_SESSION["valorCodigoPP"]);
foreach ($archivosPersonalizados as $auxPers) {
    $registrosPersonalizados[$auxPers["codigo"]] = $auxPers;
             
}

$zipname = 'file.zip';
$existe = file_exists($zipname);
$accion = $existe ? ZipArchive::OVERWRITE : ZipArchive::CREATE;
$zip = new ZipArchive;

$zip->open($zipname, $accion);

foreach ($registrosPersonalizados as $file) {
     
        $zip->addFile($file["ruta"],$file["descripcion"]);
}

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));

readfile($zipname);
```

$_SESSION["valorCodigoPP"] en esta variable de sessión obtengo el valor para obtener la consulta filtrada.

$registrosPersonalizados = [] en este array voy a guardar las filas de la consulta

$archivosPersonalizados = es la variable donde se almacena el resultado de la consulta hecha por la función getArchivostablapersonalizado()

Dentro del foreach que recorre $archivosPersonalizados utilizo el valor $auxPers["codigo"] para diferenciar las filas de la consulta.

$auxPers["codigo"] devuelve el id unico de cada fila de la consulta.

Esta es una de las rutas y nombre del archivo que obtengo en la consulta:

`descripcion="20230105150015_The way to the heaven.pdf"`

`ruta="uploads/prod_perso_16/20230105150015_The way to the heaven.pdf"`

Comment: Intenta ver el status que te arroja **$zip->status** e intenta usar esta función: https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.ziparchive.php#108601

Comment: Buenas tardes @OCHOA, gracias por responder, ahi probe la funcion zipstatusstring() con el zip. y lo que me devuelve es "No error" debido a que $zip->status devuelve 0. $zip->status y la llamada a la función zipstatusstring() la estoy realizando despues de llenar el archivo zip con el foreach. me falto agregar el cierre del zip($zip->close()). No si ese aspecto del cierre sera el problema.